# Make The navigation button highlighted

Tags: javascript, html

i have two navigation buttons

[image]

i need to change the background colour of one navigation button to orange when it is clicked,and remains unchanged untill another button is clicked,i tried some javascript codes but not working how to implement it in a simple way.

```
  <div>
        <ul class="tab">
          <li><a href="register.php" >Job Seeker</a></li>
          <li><a href="company.php" >Company</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's as simple as adding a few lines in your style.css file

for example:

```
    a:active { 
    background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Comment: color is not changing when it goes to **register.php** page or **company.php**

Comment: can you show me the html of your navigation an its css?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to look at a javascript solution, it's simply toggling the clicked element to a given class, and removing that same class from all other menu elements. The pure CSS solution is far more elegant, but this way also works. Also, if you're doing something like toggling visibility of content divs (or fetching content via ajax for each nav item clicked), this gives you a convenient place to hook that functionality.

Note that, while I did use jQuery, the same could easily be done via pure javascript, if preferred. jQuery simply allows for RAPID prototyping.

```js
$(".nav-pane li").on("click", function(){
  $(this).addClass("clicked")
         .siblings().removeClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
.nav-pane ul {
  background-color: #4059b2;
  width: 100%
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-pane ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 24%;
  height: 20px;
}
.nav-pane ul li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-pane ul li.clicked {
  background-color: #ff8605;
}
.nav-pane ul li.clicked a {
  color: #4059b2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-pane">
  <ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="#">Job Seeker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```